# Can i use two comands in one short if operator (example in description)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am intrested if i can use more then one comand in this case:

```
print(f'Some text {q[0]}!'(I wanna use second condition here) if len(q) > 0 else 'Another text')
if len(q) > 0:
    q.pop(0)
```

I want to know if i can insert belowed if in upper one to print some text if condition is true then remove first element?

Comment: Here is a nice article about [Why Code Readability is important](https://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2014/12/08/why-code-readability-is-important/). As an easy solution you can use multiple calls to `print("your text", end="")` which omits the newline

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking? The title and body are about *commands*, but the code is about *conditions*. Can you give an example or description of what you want the code to do?

Comment: Why don't you just put the `print` under the `if` statement you already have (and add an `else` clause) instead of obfuscating the code like this?

Comment: @interjay just interested if i can do something like this

Comment: Then you'll have to be more explicit about what "like this" means, because it isn't clear what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: The can be only one *expression* before the ``if``, but it can do multiple things – for example indexing, formatting, and printing. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I actually managed to use two expressin before if  print(f'text {q[0] and q.pop(0)}!' if len(queue) > 0 else 'textextext.') i was trying to ask how to do it. At this time my english is bad so i cant good to explain what I want, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments noted, the code suffers already from readability issues as is.

To answer the question, in theory you *can* nest inline-if's with parens:

```
x = 1 if cond1 else (2 if cond2 else 3)
```

However, typing stuff like this should light up a warning in your coding-brain. Often, rephrasing the code not only makes it more readable but also opens it up for further generalization (what if a third, fourth, .. condition comes along?).

Edit: also, `q.pop(0)` returns the popped element. You can use it directly in the `print` if you only need it this once. (Was that the question?)

```
print(f'Some text {q.pop(0)}!' if len(q) > 0 else 'Another text')
```

Comment: This is nice solution thank u(But i think I could not explain what I wanted). What about more condition i find this during my experiments: print(f'text {q[0] and q.pop(0)}!' if len(queue) > 0 else 'textextext.') and this work fine.

Comment: Also, it is good style to not check the length but to bool-test the list / queue variable directly, if supported: ``print(f"text {q.pop(0)} if q else "empty!")``